# SQL query with multiple joins using Rails models as reference

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause, psql

I want to select a count of all surveys where the `survey.property.address.city == "Garrison"`. I have the following models:

```
Survey
  many_to_one :property

Property
  one_to_many :surveys
  many_to_one :address

Address
  one_to_many :properties
```

How do I query using SQL?

`SELECT count(*) FROM surveys JOIN...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your table is named like rails would name those objects and you have the foreign keys that are implied by your relations:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    surveys
JOIN
    properties ON surveys.property_id = properties.id
JOIN
    addresses ON addresses.id = properties.address_id
WHERE
    addresses.city = 'Garrison'
```

Also your relations are strangely defined... I'm assuming that that is just a psuedocode version to express the relations.

edit: I corrected the second join, because I believe I had the relations backwards.

Comment: Thanks! This led me in the correct direction. I just changed `JOINS` to `JOIN` and the double quotes to single quotes.